# Using MapMarker Streets?

Tags: documentation

My company recently installed MapMarker v28.0, and the product description says it comes with something called MapMarker Streets.

My company has an older web application, and the streets we use are kept in a file called **streets.tab**. It's outdated, and a reason why we updated to the latest version of MapMarker was to get the updated street information.

I can't find *any* information on how to use MapMaker Streets or access it as data.

Answer (score 1):

The company you purchased MapMarker from should be able to send you a link to download the latest MapMarker streets data. I would contact them.